# Is an access point a layer-1, 2 or ... device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, switch

Consider an access point as a concept alone, without extended features which make it into a more complicated device such as a router.

- In what layer does an access point work? Layer 1, 2, or ...?
- Is an access point a switch? (A switch is a layer-2 device.)
- Does an access point forward data frames in a way similar to a switch?
- Does an access point have network interface(s)? Does it have MAC address(es)? (A switch doesn't have MAC address and network interface.)

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit much for a single Question post. The SuperUser format works best if you only ask a single question per Question post.

Answer (score 2):

802.11 was designed as wireless Ethernet. Like wired Ethernet, it comprises both layer 1 and 2. APs do 802.1D bridging between client STAs (802.1D bridging is what switches do).

An AP does have a MAC address. It is known as a BSSID. It is needed in order to keep track of which AP a given frame is being transmitted to/from.

Comment: Thanks. Does an AP also have a network interface, and is it also assigned an IP address? Does "STA" stand for station? Is an AP a switch not not?

Comment: @Tim: Please, put a question into the box labeled "question", not in the comment box. Also, please ask only one question per question.

Comment: @Tim 802.11, as a layer 2 (and below) protocol, knows nothing about layer 3 protocols such as IP. So 802.11 APs are not required to have IP addresses. And as I already said, they do 802.1D bridging, which is what switches do (a switch is a device that does 802.1D bridging between its ports). APs are dealing with a shared medium (a radio channel), so they don't enable as much traffic separation as wired switches do, nor do they enable full duplex operation quite like wired switches do, but, like switches, they do pay attention to destination MAC addresses when deciding where to forward frames.